# Correctly accessing parameters from a " : Base" constructor

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor

**Situation**

I'm making a small text based game using some OOP practices I learnt this academic year, the reason I'm doing this is to mostly improve the OOP that I currently know and hopefully improve some of my practices with assistance from experienced users.

So, in layman terms, I currently have an "Ork" class that's extending "Enemy" and "Enemy" is extending "Entity"

```
public class Ork : Enemy

public class Enemy : Entity
```

I have the "Enemy" class because I intend to make many unique enemy object types, not just "Ork", with this current setup I could make "Elf" or "Human" the same way. (and it's much easier to add new types in the future) Enemy has it's own constructor.

```
public Enemy(string[] Droplist, int Defaultgold, string Weaknesses, string Resistances, string[] Taunts, string Aggro, string Critchance, string Threshold, string Name, string Type,
        string Spawnzone, string _Class, int Defaultlevel, int Maxlevel, string trait, int str, int agi, int dex, int hel, int man)
    {
        //make a new entity instance.
        entity = new Entity();

        //Set all the local variables to the passed in parameters.

        setEntity(Name, Type, Spawnzone, _Class, Defaultlevel, Maxlevel, trait, str, agi, dex, hel, man);

        droplist = Droplist;
        defaultgold = Defaultgold;
        weaknesses = Weaknesses;
        resistances = Resistances;
        taunts = Taunts;
        aggro = Aggro;
        critchance = Critchance;
        threshold = Threshold;

}
```

As you can see, I set the incoming parameter to the local variable, and I use setEntity which does some of this work for me. I also have an "Entity" class, and the reason for this is, not everything that has "Stats" is an enemy, therefore I have "Entity" as the middleman.

**Problem**

The problem is at the end of this line of classes, the Ork Class.

In other programs, for instance, my Hillracing program, my constructor for a similar class would look like this:

```
public JuniorMember(string stringfirstname, string stringlastname, string stringmiddlename, string stringtitle, string strst, string strtwn, string strpc, string strEmail, int intMobile, int intHome,
            string shrnumber, string memtype, string username, string password, int noracesrun, float perraceswon, string mempic, string memclub, string gender, int memexp, int yearofbirth, int monthofbirth, int dayofbirth, string nextofkin, string docName, string docTel, string healthIssues, string parentalConsent)
            : base(stringfirstname, stringlastname, stringmiddlename, stringtitle, strst, strtwn, strpc, strEmail, intMobile, intHome, shrnumber, memtype, username, password, noracesrun, perraceswon, mempic, memclub,
            gender, memexp, yearofbirth, monthofbirth, dayofbirth)
        {
```

So, the problem is, simply put, In this program I'm looking at a similar amount of parameters, and for me, personally, looking at these parameters I don't feel as if I'm doing this correctly.

The example I gave from Hillracing works flawlessly, but I'm just wondering if this is the best way to do this, as the parameter list looks messy and it feels as if I'm creating things that have already been previously created. What I mean by this is, 90% of the information I need to create an Ork object comes from elsewhere.

**Edit**

Due to comments made, I removed the new Entity I had made in my enemy class, I now have the following Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy : Entity
{

    private string[] droplist;

    private int defaultgold;

    private string weaknesses;

    private string resistances;

    private string[] taunts;

    private string aggro;

    private string critchance;

    private string threshold;


    public string[] Droplist { get { return droplist; } set { droplist = value; } }
    public int Defaultgold { get { return defaultgold; } set { defaultgold = value; } }
    public string Weaknesses { get { return weaknesses; } set { weaknesses = value; } }
    public string Resistances { get { return resistances; } set { resistances = value; } }
    public string[] Taunts { get { return taunts; } set { taunts = value; } }
    public string Aggro { get { return aggro; } set { aggro = value; } }
    public string Critchance { get { return critchance; } set { critchance = value; } }
    public string Threshold { get { return threshold; } set { threshold = value; } }




    public void setEntity(string EnName, string EnType, string EnSpawnzone, string En_Class, int EnDefaultlevel, int EnMaxlevel, string Entrait, int Enstr, int Enagi, int Endex, int Enhel, int Enman)
    {


        setStats(Enstr, Enagi, Endex, Enhel, Enman);

        Name = EnName;
        Type = EnType;
        Spawnzone = EnSpawnzone;
        _Class = En_Class;
        Defaultlevel = EnDefaultlevel;
        Maxlevel = EnMaxlevel;
        trait = Entrait;

    }

    public Enemy(string[] Droplist, int Defaultgold, string Weaknesses, string Resistances, string[] Taunts, string Aggro, string Critchance, string Threshold) 

        :base(Name,Type,Spawnzone,_Class,Defaultlevel,Maxlevel,trait,str,agi,dex,hel,man)
    {

        //Set all the local variables to the passed in parameters.

        setEntity(Name, Type, Spawnzone, _Class, Defaultlevel, Maxlevel, trait, str, agi, dex, hel, man);

        droplist = Droplist;
        defaultgold = Defaultgold;
        weaknesses = Weaknesses;
        resistances = Resistances;
        taunts = Taunts;
        aggro = Aggro;
        critchance = Critchance;
        threshold = Threshold;

}
```

My issue here is, I don't know how to get the information from `Entity` at this point, I can't access the `Name,Type,Spawnzone,etc,etc` variables because they expect an object reference.

Comment: you can make the method without any parameter, and these parameters will be converted to properties inside your class, and if these properties are common between your entities, you might create an interface for that

Comment: `Enemy` extending `Entity`, you shouldn't have a entity variable in your `Enemy` class as it is already an entity itself.

Comment: Check the edit, I removed the entity instance from the enemy class.

Comment: This may not be entirely relevant in this example, as it is not the focus of the discussion, but in general it is good practice to avoid returning arrays from properties. Consider using collections, or changing those properties to methods. [Link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Entity` should be a base class that `Enemy` extends (with the additional stats that not all entities have). From `Enemy`'s constructor you should call the parent `Entity` constructor. This makes sense because `Enemy` "is a(n)" `Entity`.

Whereas, currently, your setup is such that `Enemy` "has a(n)" `Entity`, which doesn't make sense.

---

**Edit**

You have this already:

```
public class Ork : Enemy
```

I'm saying, you also need to have this:

```
public class Enemy : Entity
```

And C# I think class base class constructors automatically, so you don't have to do anything else. Just do everything common to all `Entity`s in the Entity constructor, `Enemy`s in Enemy, and so forth.

Comment: Enemy does extend Entity.

`public class Enemy : Entity`

Comment: Are you sure? Currently it seems like you're creating a new instance of `Entity` within the `Enemy`'s constructor.

Comment: Not necessarily "wrong," but that isn't extending the class, no. Extending the class is as you've done from Enemy or Ork. To complete the hierarchy, you want to do: Entity to Enemy to Ork, not create an an Entity object within Enemy.

Comment: Okay, so say I removed that line of code, what would I replace it with? A ":Base" to Entity from Enemy?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I see that you just edited to clarify that your `Enemy` class extends `Entity`.  Then I'm not understanding why you are instantiating an `Entity` class inside the `Enemy` constructor.  What is the logical relationship between `Entity` and `Enemy`?  Is `Enemy` a type of `Entity`?  Or, does `Enemy` have an `Entity`?*

Perhaps you can consider passing in the `Entity` instance to the `Enemy` constructor to avoid having to pass in all the individual components of the `Entity` class to the `Enemy` constructor.  Something like this:

```
public class Entity {
    // other code

    public Entity(string Type, string Spawnzone, string _Class, int Defaultlevel, int Maxlevel, string trait, int str, int agi, int dex, int hel, int man) {
        // move setEntity code here.
    }

    // other code
}

public class Enemy {

    // other code

    public Enemy(string[] Droplist, int Defaultgold, string Weaknesses, string Resistances, string[] Taunts, string Aggro, string Critchance, string Threshold, string Name, Entity entity) {
            this.entity = entity;

            droplist = Droplist;
            defaultgold = Defaultgold;
            weaknesses = Weaknesses;
            resistances = Resistances;
            taunts = Taunts;
            aggro = Aggro;
            critchance = Critchance;
            threshold = Threshold;
    }

    // other code
}
```

Comment: `Enemy` is a type of `Entity`. just like `Player` or `Item`  could be a type of `Entity`.

The logical reasoning for this is the `Entity` class contains items that will be used by `Item`, `Enemy` and `Player` in the future. like stats, everything has stats.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Enemy` class is containing an instance of `Entity`. Which is a wrong practice in your case. And if your `Enemy` class is extended by `Entity` then you can use its constructor to set generic values to parent class. Just like you have done it in HillRacing program.

(Make sure your `Enemy` class does not have a member of `Entity` Type. if it is base of `Enemy` )

```
public class Entity 
{
    public string Type;
    public string Spawnzone;
    public string _Class;
    public string Defaultlevel;
    public string Maxlevel;
    public string Trait;
    public string str;
    public string agi;
    public string dex;
    public string hel;
    public string man;

    public Entity(string Type, string Spawnzone, string _Class, int Defaultlevel, int Maxlevel, string trait, int str, int agi, int dex, int hel, int man) 
    {
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Spawnzone = Spawnzone;
        this._Class = _Class;
        this.Defaultlevel = Defaultlevel;
        this.Maxlevel = Maxlevel;
        this.Trait = trait;
        this.str = str;
        this.agi = agi;
        this.dex = dex;
        this.hel = hel;
        this.man = man;
    }

}

public class Enemy 
{
    public string[] droplist;;
    public int defaultgold;
    public string weaknesses;
    public string resistances;
    public string[] taunts;
    public string aggro;
    public string critchance;
    public string threshold;


    public Enemy(string[] Droplist, int Defaultgold, string Weaknesses, string Resistances, string[] Taunts, string Aggro, string Critchance, string Threshold, string Name, string Type, string Spawnzone, string _Class, int Defaultlevel, int Maxlevel, string trait, int str, int agi, int dex, int hel, int man ) 
    : base(Type, Spawnzone, _Class, Defaultlevel, Maxlevel, trait, str, agi, dex, hel, man)
    {

        droplist = Droplist;
        defaultgold = Defaultgold;
        weaknesses = Weaknesses;
        resistances = Resistances;
        taunts = Taunts;
        aggro = Aggro;
        critchance = Critchance;
        threshold = Threshold;
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you provide an example?